# CSS 1x1 inch box on screen

Tags: css

How can i specify a box to be 1x1 inches. That should be printed as 1x1 inch box and will be seen as 1x1 inch box on screen.

Comment: Read more about lengths in CSS here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units

Comment: You can't do this. It's impossible to accurately render a 1x1 inch square across every platform and resolution. You are completely reliant on an accurate pixels-per-inch on each client, which you won't get.

Answer (score 8):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eR9CS/

**Inches:**

```
<div style="background-color: red; width: 1in; height: 1in;"></div>​
```

**Centimeters:**

```
<div style="background-color: red; width: 1cm; height: 1cm;"></div>​
```

**Relative length units**

- `em` The computed font-size.
- `ex` The height of a lowercase "x".
- `px` Pixels, relative to the viewing device.
- `%` Percentage.
- `rem` The font size of the root element.
- `vw` The viewport width.
- `vh` The viewport height.
- `vm` The smaller value of viewport width or height.
- `ch` Zero-width (width of the zero glyph in the rendering font).

**Absolute length units**

- `in` Inches (1 inch = 2.54 centimeters).
- `cm` Centimeters.
- `mm` Millimeters.
- `pt` Points (1 point = 1/72 inches).
- `pc` Picas (1 pica = 12 points).

If you want to use centimeters everywhere but want an inch, use `style="width: 2.54cm; height: 2.54cm;"` since `1 inch = 2.54cm`.

Comment: I actually measured the first box width on my screen; it’s about 27 mm, so more than one inch.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You are right, it's strange... After some tests, `2.72cm` will give you a "real" inch on the screen.

Comment: I don’t think so `1in` equals `2.54cm` in CSS and in physical measurements. Those units have a fixed relationship, but the CSS units do not exactly correspond to the physical measurement units.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. You can only get some approximations. Setting the width and height to `1in` is your best shot, but it’s not a particularly good shot, as you can see if you measure the dimensions (on different devices). As the CSS3 Units module [describes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths), the so-called absolute units can be anchored either to physical units or to pixels. The fixed relations like `1in` = `96px` then implies that (except by accident) CSS `in` is not the real physical inch or CSS `px` is not the real physical pixel.

On paper, you could expect a physical unit to be the anchor unit, so that `in` would really be the inch. But even this expectation often fails.